# How to use asymmetric encryption between my console & wpf app?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption-asymmetric

I am stuck when it comes to keep data save over web, I have a console application that acts as my host portal (using owin selfhost) to handle requests and I have a WPF application that my users can use at any time, this WPF application is suppose to ask for information like my connection string info to connect to the database, since i did not want to put that information hardcoded in the application (for decompile reasons) I decide to let the WPF application make a request over web (using WebClient) to receive the database connection string information, but since we cant just send that back as plain text, we do need encryption and there is where I am stuck.
I use a class library to store the encryption methods (encrypt/decrypt) and implement that library in both applications, when a request comes in my console application is encrypting the data to send it back to the WPF application but my WPF application cannot decrypt the data, there is where I am running into exceptions thus the data stays encrypted and is basicly useless at this moment.

Can somebody please explain me how to fix this problem so any user can make requests with the WPF application to my console application while everything been send over the web is encrypted and safe?
I am fairly new when it comes to this topic, and when I look around on the internet I only get examples where encryption and decryption is done in the same application with build in classes inside the application itself rather then using libraries to share it across multiple applications within the same solution. So far nothing really helped me, i have been looking for 2 days for this now, watched a ton of youtube videos but they all end up the same using it in the same application...
If i do that aswell, it works fine, but once I try with my WPF application the data fails to decrypt.

I hope somebody can lead me to a solution with this.
My appologies if my english is a bit broken, I am trying my best to improve this.
If you need more information to understand my problem please ask, I provide as much info as I can

Comment: you have encryption already - just use HTTPS ...  the probem is with authentication and authorization

Comment: @Selvin The problem is not with that, atleast for now.. the problem is that when I get the data encrypted back (from console => to wpf - where it is encrypted on the console side and send encrypted to the wpf app) I cannot decrypt it with the WPF app... and i dont understand why not, both applications use the same class library with same encryptor class